# Python: for key in gasCount: NameError: name 'gasCount' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
import string

def getFile():
    filename = input('Filename: ') #the file name should be .csv
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    firstline = True

    Line = file.readline()
    if Line == None or Line == '':
        return None

    if firstline: # I do not want to read the field names
        Line = file.readline() # there is more to read
        firstline = False # so I skip them. the code assuems 

    return file

#Count the number of (T's) in the field [correct]
def calcT(correct):
    global tCount
    found = False
    for ch in correct:#look at each character in turn
        if ch in 'tT':
            found = True

    if found:
        tCount +=1

#How many times does the least common string appear in the field [gas]

def gas_Count(gas):
    global gasCount
    if gas in gasCount:
        gasCount[gas] += 1
    else:
        gasCount[gas] = 1

smallest = 100000
for key in gasCount:
    if gasCount[key] < smallest:
        smallest = gasCount[key]

answers = []
for key in gasCount:
    if gasCount[key] == smallest:
        answers.append(key)


#Find the sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408)
def sum_quant(quant):
    global qsum
    if quant < 408:
        qsum += quant
code="0"        
#How many values in the 'code' field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9?
def checkString(astring):
    if len(code)  != 10:
        return False
    if not astring[0] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[1] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[2] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[3] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[4]=='(':
        return False
    if not astring[5] in string.ascii_lowercase:
        return False
    if not astring[6] in string.digits:
        return False
    if not astring[7]=='+':
        return False
    if not astring[8]==')':
        return False
    if not astring[9] in string.digits:
        return False
    return True

if checkString(code):
    global cCount
    cCount += 1


#What is the average value of the numbers in the field [age] in the range (30) and (107) inclusive 
def average_age(age):
    global tAge
    global ageCount
    if age >= 30 and age <=107:
        tAge += age
    ageCount += 1

#Find the sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428) inclusive 
def sum_Length(leng):
    global lensum
    if leng >= 2.482 and leng <= 6.428:
        lensum += leng

#count the lines where gas's have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318
def calcGas(gas, quant):
    global clines
    if gas == 'Nitrogen' or quant < 318:
        clines += 1

def processLine(Line):
    Line = Line.strip()
    fields = Line.split(',')

    correct = fields[0]
    gas = fields[1]
    quant = int(fields[2])
    code = fields[3]
    age = int(fields[4])
    leng = float(fields[5])
    calcT(correct)
    sum_Length(leng)
    calcGas(gas, quant)
    average_age(age)
    sum_quant(quant)
    gas_Count(gas)
    checkString(astring)

def processFile(data):

    for line in data:
        processLine(line)

    data.close()

def displayResults():
    #Count the number of (T's) in the field [correct]
    print('The number of (T) in the field [correct]: %d'%(tCount))
    print('-' *10)  
    print(gasCount)
    print('-' *10)
    print(cCount)
    #Find the sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408)
    print('The sum of the values in the field [quant] less than (408): %d'%(qsum))
    print('-' *10)
    #How many values in the 'code' field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9?
    #print('The values in the code field do not match the format 9999(x9+)9: %d'%()
    print('-' *10)
    #What is the average value of the numbers in the field [age] in the range (30) and (107) inclusive
    print((tAge/ageCount))
    print('-' *10)
    #Find the sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428) inclusive 
    print('The sum of the numbers in field [length] between (2.482) and (6.428): %6.3f'%(lensum))
    print('-' *10)
    #count the lines where gas's have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318
    print('The lines where gas have the value (Nitrogen) *or* quant is less than 318: %d' %(clines))


tCount = 0
gasCount = {}
qsum = 0
cCount = 0
ageCount = 0
tAge = 0
lensum = 0
clines = 0
myfile = getFile()
processFile(myfile)
displayResults()
```

getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ultra\Downloads\3215402\3215402\3215402 Stage 1 Function.py", line 63, in <module>
```

editing to this for tobias_k:

```
def gas_Count(gas):
    global gasCount
    if gas in gasCount:
        gasCount[gas] += 1
    else:
        gasCount[gas] = 1
    smallest = 100000  
for key in gasCount:  
    if gasCount[key] < smallest:    
         smallest = gasCount[key]  
answers = []  
for key in gasCount:  
    if gasCount[key] == smallest:  
            answers.append(key)
```

gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ultra\Downloads\3215402\3215402\3215402 Stage 1 Function.py", line 57, in <module>
    for key in gasCount:
NameError: name 'gasCount' is not defined
```

Comment: Well, you (seem to) never initialize `gasCount`. But if this is line 58, you are not showing us your full code, so this is hard to tell. Even if you use `global`, you'll have to have a line like `gasCount = {}` somewhere in your code to initialize it as an empty dictionary.

Comment: what do you mean initialize it? sorry im very new! ill edit main post with full code

Comment: ok i edited main post

Comment: Should the two loops below `smallest = ` and `answers = ` be part of the function defined right above them?

Comment: Is the error really on line 63 or have you changed stuff since?

Comment: theres a error with the whole gasCount whatever i do to edit it or change it i get a error where gasCount is not defined, after doing what tobias_k said and made smallest = and answers = part of the same funtion i get the same error except on line 57 most likely because i removed the space of course.

Comment: Edited main post to tobias_k suggestion